# Is it possible to manage or call jobs of a Databricks cluster from Java Code?

Tags: java, azure, databricks

I have a succesful connection in a Java simple code using jdbc string connection. I would just want to know if calling a job of Azure Databricks cluster from Java code would be possible and how?

The only thing that seems possible to do is calling SQL Statements using this kind of connection but no calls to the databricks cluster. Any ideas?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You can start jobs remotely by using the [Databricks Jobs REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs#--run-now)